# Executing a function only once in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to retrieve an image dimension from a temp file. Which is successful through the following:

```
after_post_process :save_ratio_image

  def save_ratio_image
    geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original])
    self.ratiolongdivlarg = geo.width / geo.height
  end
```

Though I need to repeatdly save this model over time because on top of the attachment I have some other fields and one more Paperclip attachment too.

The above code then throw an error **Cannot find the geometry of a file with a blank name** I guess this is because the temp file no longer exists the other times I save this model..

Is there a way to call this function only once (ie the first time a record from this model is saved) ?

Comment: There is an `after_create` callback that would call the method only when the record is saved for the first time.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `after_create` callback instead of what you're currently using. It will only call the function when the record is saved for the first time.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html